# Why my javascript alert doesn't show up

Tags: javascript

I tested the code below in google chrome but alert shows up why ? (I took it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163419.aspx)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function filter(pred, arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    var filtered = []; // shorter version of new Array();
    // iterate through every element in the array...
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++) {
        var val = arr[i];
        // if the element satisfies the predicate let it through
        if (pred(val)) {
            filtered.push(val);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}

var someRandomNumbers = [12, 32, 1, 3, 2, 2, 234, 236, 632, 7, 8];
var numbersGreaterThan100 = filter(function (x) {
    return (x > 100) ? true : false;
}, someRandomNumbers);

// displays 234, 236, 632
alert(numbersGreaterThan100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your title and question body conflict. Please clarify.

Comment: Probably an error in your script somewhere -  check the chrome console for errors

Comment: did u try replacing "&lt;" with "<" such as: for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

Comment: Heh, someone needs to tell MSDN to correct their article too.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Nothing wrong with the article ... He just copied an `HTML Encoded` snippet :)

Comment: @Xander - No, the article HTML literally says: `for(var i = 0; i &amp;lt; len; i++) {`

Comment: @MikeChristensen Oh, ok - then they must be deterring "coders" like OP who just copy and paste...

Answer (score 5):

You have an error here, where some html didn't quite come over correctly.  This is preventing your `alert` from being reached.

```
for(var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++) {
```

change it to:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
for(var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++) {
```

You have an HTML entity instead of a less-than sign. Fix that and it'll work.

Side-note:

```
function(x) { return (x > 100) ? true : false; }
```

This was written by the Department of Redundancy Department. Use `return x>100;` instead.

Comment: Dear Department of Redundancy Department: Your code is shorter, but spelling it out the long way makes it much more readable to me.

Comment: Really, @DOK? I find the reverse to be true. To each one's own.

Answer (score 1):

You have "special-character" HTML in your For loop.

Change:

```
for(var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++) {
```

To:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

I did that, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I am seeing is: `for(var i = 0; i &lt; len; i++) {`

This should be: `for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {`

Notice the "<" instead of  `&lt;`

Answer (score 1):

When you copy and paste sometimes you get HTML special characters. In this case, you have & lt; instead of < in your for loop. Change it and it works.

Rule of thumb: in Javascript, when a line doesn't work there is a syntax error 95% or the time